# HyperCard dashboard type

Tags: macos, hypercard, hypertalk

Is there a name that explains the type of dashboard like that of HyperCard. A dashboard that has icons sitting on top of a rectangular box?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The first unique UI element of HyperCard that comes to mind is the tear-off tools palette. Can you provide an image?

Answer (score 1):

In HyperCard, we called it the Home stack. In other software, it could be called the Home window, main window, navigation window, start center, launcher, etc.

Answer (score 0):

“Windoid” is the name given to a floating palette like that.

It includes the tools palette and also includes the message box.

These are like mini windows without the normal system controls that are not focusable, have a frontal z-index, and do not respond to system commands or shortcuts to close them. They can respond to commands from HyperCard (including in HyperTalk scripts) to open, close and move them.

They otherwise have similar behavior to non-HyperCard equivalents such as tool palettes, color pickers and some ‘desk accessories’ in the MacOS (pre OSX of course). These equivalents can be manipulated with AppleScript.

Comment: There was no HyperScript in HyperCard. Probably, you mean HyperTalk.